# How can I programatically add an item to this dialog?

Tags: windows, insert, dialog

When I insert an SD card, Windows XP/Vista/7 presents a dialog asking the user what they want to do with the contents. How can I add an item to this list for only certain types of data? (Like photos, music, etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Implement an Autoplay Handler](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/AutoplayDemo.aspx) (programmatically)

[Add Custom Options to the Windows AutoPlay Dialog](http://lifehacker.com/371677/add-custom-options-to-the-windows-autoplay-dialog) (not programmatically)